# OnePage Checkout blank page after step 5 (no errors)

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, onepage-checkout

I have a very strange and redundant error on the OnePage Checkout of a Magento shop (ver. 1.9.3.6). After step 5 (Payment Information) I have a blank page only displaying the contact e-mail Address. It should show the order overview. 
I viewed the console for any errors, checked server side error logs, activated and checked the Magento error log and update the index.php and changed PHP settings to display errors. Nothing! Not one error. 
I've also wiped the cache and session files.
I'm totally clueless what the issue could be. I even copied onepage.phtml from base to the theme folder. 
Also changed the PHP Version from 5.6.* to 7.0.* and updated memory_limit to 512M and max_execution_time to 600.

Any suggestions what I could try to solve the issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I restarted the server to, just to make sure. Didn't help either.

Answer (score 0):

Today I found the issue. 
It seems to be some false settings in the Tax section. I changed everything to "Including Taxes" and here we are, the last step is running again. Orders can now be done again. 
Hope this helps someone running into a similar issue.